# Execute batch of promise with Promise.allSettled()

Tags: node.js, promise

With node v10.15.1 I try to use `Promise.allSettled()` to executes batches of Promise but it throw me an error

> TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function

Is `Promise.all()` returning a promise ?

The `Main` function below return an object.
Other functions use some Promises to create its "sub-object".

Why I need "batch of promise" :
To create a sub-object, all the required promises must be settled.
But not all the sub-objects are needed in the "main object".

```js
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const si = require('systeminformation');

function getFoo() {
  // all these promises have to be settled to construct the sub-object
  return Promise.all([si.system(), si.chassis()]).then(([system, chassis]) => {
    return { /* hidden for brevity : use system and chassis to return a single object */ };
  })
  .catch(ex => { /* hidden for brevity */ });
}

function getBar() {
  // all these promises have to be settled to construct the sub-object
  return Promise.all([si.osInfo(), si.uuid()]).then(([osInfo, uuid]) => {
    return { /* hidden for brevity : use osInfo and uuid to return a single object */ };
  })
  .catch(ex => { /* hidden for brevity */ });
}

function getBaz() {
  // all these promises have to be settled to construct the sub-object
  return Promise.all([os.networkInterfaces(), si.networkInterfaceDefault()]).then(([interfaces, defaultInterface]) => {
    return { /* hidden for brevity : use interfaces and defaultInterface to return a single object */ };
  })
  .catch(ex => { /* hidden for brevity */ });
}

function Main() {
  // some of these promises can be rejected
  Promise.allSettled([ getFoo(), getBar(), getBaz() ])
    .then(([foo, bar, baz]) => {
      return { foo, bar, baz }
    })
    .catch(ex => { /* hidden for brevity */ });
}

Main();
```

#### One Example of expected object

```js
{
  foo: {
    prop: 'example',
    someOtherProps: 'We are there!'
  },
  baz: {
    test: 50
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled allSettled is currently in draft stage, not standard. Browser compatibility shows ? for node.js

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Promise.allSettled is available in node version >= 12.9](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.9.0/)

Answer (score 8):

<strike>[`Promise.allSettled`](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators#promise.allsettled) is not yet available for Node environments.</strike>

**UPDATE:** This feature is [available as of node 12.9.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.9.0/).

For older versions you can use an npm package as a workaround: [es-shims/Promise.allSettled](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.allSettled).

Answer (score 4):

```
Update zone.js
```

open package.json and change zone.js: "~0.XX.X" to zone.js: "~0.10.3"

```
 "dependencies": {
 "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
}
```

Then run npm install

Answer (score 3):

```js
allSettled = function(promiseList) {
    let results = new Array(promiseList.length);

    return new Promise((ok, rej) => {

        let fillAndCheck = function(i) {
            return function(ret) {
                results[i] = ret;
                for(let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    if (results[j] == null) return;
                }
                ok(results);
            }
        };

        for(let i=0;i<promiseList.length;i++) {
            promiseList[i].then(fillAndCheck(i), fillAndCheck(i));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. At the time of this post, `allSettled` is on stage 4.

There are plan to add `allSettled` to Promise into typescript and polyfilling is already available using babel and [core-js@3](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). Or you could use one of the many [userland implementation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled#userland-implementations) available. It may take some time before it get to nodejs nativity, but that doesn't stop you from using it anyway right now.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, `Promise.allSettled()` is not available yet.

You can still use Promise.all(), it is indeed returning a promise that resolves when ALL promises inside the array resolves, or rejects when one of them rejects.