# Promise.allSettled is not a function in jest test, how to mock?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

I have an action that uses Promise.allSettled to return multiple stat objects from an API.
When I run the tests with mocking I get the error 
`Promise.allSettled is not a function`

I have a get endpoint to returns different types of stats.
`myapi.com/get_stats/:type`

I have an action for this API as follows

```
  const types = ['seo', 'referrers', 'clicks', 'posts', 'videos'];
  const promises = [];
  types.forEach(type =>
    promises.push(
      api().stats.getStats(type),
    ),
  );
  Promise.allSettled(promises).then(res => {
    const { statData, statErrors } = mapData(res); // Data manipulation
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_STATS_RESOLVED, payload: { statData, statErrors } });
  });
```

My Test set up

```
jest.mock('api-file.js', () => ({
  api: () => ({
     stats: {
         getStats: type => {
           switch (type) {
              case: 'seo':
                return mockSeoStats;
           }
         }
      } 
  })
}));
```

in beforeEach()

```
mockSeoStats.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ value: {data: myData} }));
```

I can see that the Action is receiving these mocked values, but Promise.allSettled is complaining

I assume it's having a hard time with the jest mock structure

So, how can i mock Promise.allSettled to just return what I expect it to, instead of looking at my mocked functions?

Comment: To get an useful answer, try to boil down your question to the essential information and provide examples of what happens versus what you would like to happen.

Comment: Does `promise.all` work?

Comment: it has [been added](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) in Node 12.9(and jest is run under NodeJS). So you either should update your Node or provide polyfill for this method.

Comment: Promise.allSettled works in implementation. It is only in testing with Jest that I have an issue.

The code itself is functional and works as expected.

Comment: I was using ts-jest@24.2.0 and jest@24.9.0 with node v8.9.4 and the application was working but the tests for code using allSettled was failing. I just updated node to v12.16.1 keeping jest and ts-jest versions and the tests work.

Answer (score 5):

A similar question was asked at [Execute batch of promise with Promise.allSettled()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576249/execute-batch-of-promise-with-promise-allsettled)
Promise.allSettled is available from Node version 12.0 +

You can update node using Node's version manager

```sh
nvm ls
# Look for a 12.17.0 version (latest)
nvm install 12.17.0
# Automatically switches to new version
npm run test
# Should properly run your Promise.all
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -3):

Try wrapping `Promise.allSettled` in `try-catch` block if you don't want to update node js.

Example:

```
try {
  Promise.allSettled([
    // your code
  ]).finally(() => {
    // your code`enter code here`
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('promise.allSettled', e);
}
```