# TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function in AWX while syncing a local gitlab project

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, gitlab

I'm facing a strange issue trying to sync a gitlab project to a newly installed AWX in k8s using this link:
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-ansible-awx-on-ubuntu-linux/

So I have my kuber up and running, and AWX is also installed - I successfully access it via web-page.

In addition, I have a rather old gitlab and AWX installs up and running, couple of projects inside them. I can successfully sync these projects between old instances.

Now I try to sync a simple test-project from old gitlab to new AWX on kuber.
And no matter what I try, I keep getting thi error:

```
TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function
dfe/<@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:3268408
Fl@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:887071
6813/t.unstable_runWithPriority@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:923875
Vi@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:827390
Dl@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:886532
yl@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:878022
Yi/<@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:827613
6813/t.unstable_runWithPriority@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:923875
Vi@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:827390
Yi@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:827560
Ki@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:827493
fl@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:875496
Io@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:847148
e/<@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:1081861
u@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:914699
c/a._invoke</<@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:914488
j/</<@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:915128
An@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:1035251
o@http://10.131.64.210:30080/static/js/main.12d85f28.js:2:1035457
```

I tried googling it with partial success - people talk about this function
being used in different projects with same errors, but I couldn't find anything of a "straight help", I'm not a developer, unfortunately.

Comment: That [`node.js` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576249/) seems has nothing to do with Ansible at all. So you could remove that tag. Furthermore, the post as it is currently leaves out almost all necessary information about your environments, setups, used software version. etc.

Comment: Thank's for your reply!
Could please someone point me to the most effective "solution-seeking-algorithm" in such a situation?
I can't seem to find node.js installed on any of the awx-pod containers, all other functions seem to be working fine, including REST API, managing inventories projects, etc.
Like I miss something very simple, but not obvious and can't seem to google anything out? just point me to correct google-request at least :))
Thank's in advance!

Comment: The post as it is currently leaves out almost all necessary information about your environments, setups, used software version. etc. Therefore it might not be possible to provide an (meaningful) answer, at least not for me.

Comment: > The post as it is currently leaves out almost all necessary information about your environments, setups, used software version. etc
I'm really happy about this, though I cannot understand why
>  it might not be possible to provide an (meaningful) answer,
But thx for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply changing the browser to edge, as stupid as it seems, oh yes.
Firefox - even the last one - is not capable of handling Promise function correctly.
Couldn't find any solution to make it work inside firefox, though it runs flawlessly in Edge.
Peace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).